# Объединения нескольких list списков средствами "LINQ"

Tags: .net, list, linq, vb.net

Есть такой код:

- Как используя LINQ объединить эти списки?
- Или возможно как то это без LINQ можно просто сделать?

```vb
Dim a As New List(Of Integer)
Dim b As New List(Of Integer)
Dim c As New List(Of Integer)

a.Add(1)
b.Add(2)
c.Add(3)
```

Comment: И за что минус?

Comment: Наверное, на неясную формулировку. Под *объединением* имеется в виду *join* или *concatenation*? *Join* здесь не получится, значения ключей различны, соединить списки не получится. *Concatenate* получится, но для него LINQ вообще не нужен. В целом, про что вопрос, не ясно.

Comment: Имелось ввиду UNION

Comment: @MarkShevchenko обычно если в вопросе есть неясность то ее уточняют в комментах а не лепят минус как бы.

Comment: Если что, минус ставил не я. Я посмотрел на вопрос и предположил, за что заминусовали. Вы,возможно, и правы, но у вас большой рейтинг, вы не новичок на сайте. Поэтому, видимо, и ожидания к качеству вопроса высокие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

тут выбор из двух вариантов

добавлять в уже существующий массив:

```
Dim d As New List(Of Integer)
d.AddRange(a)
d.AddRange(b)
d.AddRange(c)
```

либо соединить в новый объект (функция Concat в отличии от AddRange не меняет объект, на котором вызывается):

```
Dim d = a.Concat(b).Concat(c).ToList()
```

Comment: Второй вариант выдает. `Дополнительные сведения: Не удалось привести тип объекта "<ConcatIterator>d__59 1[System.Int32]" к типу "System.Collections.Generic.List 1[System.Int32]".`

Comment: Первый вариант выдает, выражение не порождает значение.

Comment: прошу прощения, не силен в бейсике. исправил ошибки.

Comment: спасибо вам за правильный ответ. Я поменял отметку что именно ваш ответ правильный. Хотел бы обратить внимание на одну деталь, немного неприятную. Например сказать, я не силен в шарпе, это в 99% случаев будет означать что говорят о C# а не например о F# или J# но говорить о VB.NET что это бейсик, совершенно неверно, ибо под этим словом можно подразумевать очень многое. :)

Comment: Особенно учитывая тот факт что компилятор в Visual Studio 2015 был полностью переписан на языке VB.NET :)

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь функцией Union()

```
Dim result As List(Of Integer) = a.Union(b).Union(c).ToList()
```

Comment: И с чего бы union? В вопросе ничего нет про удаление дубликатов.

Comment: @Qwertiy кстати резонное замечание, если сравнивать с питоном то там простые операции объединения списков дают другой результат...

Comment: @Qwertiy  а причем здесь  удаление дубликатов. Посмотрите описание функции на MSDN:" Enumerable.Union Метод

Пространство имен:
    System.Linq 

Сборки:
    System.Linq.dll, System.Core.dll, netstandard.dll

Находит объединение множеств, представленных двумя последовательностями."

Comment: @WinnerIT, посмотри внимательно на фразу _"объединение множеств"_ - дубликаты удаляются.

Answer (score 0):

На выбор:

- ```
  A.Concat(B).Concat(C)
  ```
- ```
  { A, B, C }.SelectMany(Function(Y) Y)
  ```

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim A As New List(Of Integer) From { 1, 2, 3 }
        Dim B As New List(Of Integer) From { 4, 5, 6 }
        Dim C As New List(Of Integer) From { 7, 8, 9 }

        For Each X In A.Concat(B).Concat(C)
            Console.Write("{0} ", X)
        Next X

        Console.WriteLine()

        For Each X In { A, B, C }.SelectMany(Function(Y) Y)
            Console.Write("{0} ", X)
        Next X
    End Sub
End Module
```